# How to create a view in Drupal 7 that shows only a filtered list based on a field of the current user

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, entityreference

I'm trying to create a **view** that filters the resulting pages (content type) based on the association of the same entity of the current logged in **user**.

This is my situation in detail:

1. **user: field_organizations** (n) (Entity reference field to Content type : **Organization**)
2. **page: field_organization** (1) (Entity reference field to Content type : **Organization**)

for example:

Users

1. **Alice**: field_organizations = [o1, o2, o3]
2. **Bob** - field_organizations = [o2, o3]
3. **Charlie** - field_organizations = [o1]

Pages

- **page1**: organization = o1
- **page2**: organization = o1
- **page3**: organization = o2
- **page4**: organization = o3

The view should return the following results:

- **Alice** = [page1, page2, page3, page4]
- **Bob** = [page3, page4]
- **Charlie** = [page1, page2]

I already tried to create a view (of users) that based on the current user ID (contextual filter) returns only the organizations associated to that user, but the problem is that I cannot use this view in the field_organization of the content type page to filter the results. It requires a view of content not a view of users.

Creating a view of organization I'm not able to reach the current user ID through the contextual filter.

Someone can suggest me an alternative solution?
thx

Answer (score 0):

From the first glance, it looks like you should set up a relationship between users and content types in the "Relationship" section of the view.
In addition look at this module - [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view). Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I agree with you. The view of users that I created, returns exactly what I need, but I can't use this type of view in the content type field_organization. A view to be eligible in this field has to be a view of Organizations, but in this particular view I can't find a waty to show the correct result. I can't reach the user field_organizations and I can't return the filterd list of organizations.

Comment: Look at this module - [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view). May be it will be helpful for you.